# Switching orientation in Android

Tags: android, orientation

i have any troubles with switching between orientation from portrait to landscape.

i made this page cause i don't have permission to add images

http://www.guitart.comyr.com/

There are my codes and two images.

I've tried to make some small application to test switching, i made same folders as you can see at the page and this small test app works fine. But my original app doesnt work.

Sorry for English.

Comment: To me all seems fine.Can you try this import - >
 import View.OnClickListener

Comment: Also try to clean the project in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_menu_info"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:background="@drawable/info64"
   android:src="@drawable/info64" />
```

in both menu.xml layouts(layout|layout-land) folders? If you change the orientation to landscape, your app automatically uses the xmls from your layout-land folder. Eclipse don't recognize if the ID exists in both orientations. Eclipse can't stop you from building because it's no error but it could at least give you a warning imo.

No problem :)

Comment: Yes I only copied main.xml to my layout-land folder. I didn't noticed that could be wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just copy the layout file from layout folder and paste it in "layout-land". check the id's of the views because logcat is showing nullPointerException in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_menu_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/info64"
        android:src="@drawable/info64" />
```

remove

```
android:src="@drawable/info64"
```

line from this button's property.thats the problem.and you are done.